# Magento 2 : Automatically rating for product has image

Tags: magento2, database, product-images, ratings, automation

Automatically add four stars on the results page, products page, for all products that do have an image. (Use the database direct to update the stars for the SKUs that have **`image_count` = true**)

Use the **`image_count`** column in Magento to sort for products that have an image.

**image_count is a boolean**, 'true' or' 'false'. Any help. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In Your Module try this in

> Vendor/HelloWorld/Model/ProductReviews.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\HelloWorld\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
class ProductReviews extends AbstractModel{

    protected $_ratingFactory;
    protected $_productFactory;
    protected $_ratingFactory;
    protected $_reviewFactory;

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
            \Magento\Review\Model\RatingFactory $ratingFactory,
            \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $reviewFactory,
        ) {
            $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
            $this->_ratingFactory = $ratingFactory;
            $this->_reviewFactory = $reviewFactory;
        }

    public function getReviewCollection($productId){
        $collection = $this->_reviewFactory->create()
        ->addStatusFilter(
            \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
        )->addEntityFilter(
            'product',
            $productId
        )->setDateOrder();

    }

    public function getRatingCollection(){
        $ratingCollection = $this->_ratingFactory->create()
        ->getResourceCollection()
        ->addEntityFilter(
            'product' 
        )->setPositionOrder()->setStoreFilter(
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        )->addRatingPerStoreName(
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        )->load();

        return $ratingCollection->getData();
    }

}
```

Approve it, if it helps You, Thanks

Comment: Thank for the answer. How can I get image_count in database.

Comment: here is your answer below, if it these two answer usefull to you approve then, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**The following query returns the number of images per product:**

```
SELECT sku,count(*) FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS a 
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity` AS b ON a.entity_id = b.entity_id 
group by sku
```

> I am not sure if it works properly in case of complex products or bundle. But it gives you an idea about how to proceed.

More generally, you should use the following Magento tables:

- catalog_product_entity (for product ids)
- catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity (for image and product relationship)
- catalog_product_entity_media_gallery (for images path)